# Updating textbox on dropdown select with CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a dropdown that upon selecting a value, an ajax call occurs and that should populate a textbox. The basic functionality is working (in that it calls to a function in my controller which looks up the value), but I can't seem to get the value for the textbox to display the retrieved value.

Instead of the textbox HTML code appearing like this (assuming 100.00 is the returned value)

```
<input name="data['Visit']['room_rate'] type="text" id="VisitRoomRate" value="100.00"></input>
```

It's updating to this (value is between the input tags and not set to value ="100")

```
<input name="data['Visit']['room_rate'] type="text" id="VisitRoomRate">100.00</input>
```

Here is the code in the view displays the retrieved value

```
//get_room_rate.ctp 

 <?php echo $room_rate; ?>
```

Here's the code for the ajax call

```
$this->Js->get('#VisitRoomId')->event('change', 
    $this->Js->request(array(
        'controller'=>'visits',
        'action'=>'getRoomRate'
        ), array(
        'update'=>'#VisitRoomRate',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true
            ))
        ))
);
```

**Edit I got it to work although I'm not sure if it's the correct way to go about it**

I changed my form so the room rate input is in a div like this

```
?><div id="room_rate_update"><?php
    echo $this->Form->input('room_rate', array('label' => 'Room Rate (numbers only)'));
?></div><?php
```

And then in my view which displays the new number I swapped it to the input like so

```
<label for="VisitRoomRate">Room Rate </label>
<input name="data[Visit][room_rate]" maxlength="10" type="text" id="VisitRoomRate" required="required" value="<?php echo $room_rate; ?>"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the 'update' option to update the DOM item supplied, use the 'success' option to name a callback function to be fired on successful completion of the ajax call. Then in that function update the input's value instead of the text. (Possibly a little easier with straight javascript or jquery as opposed to the Cake JS Helper)

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::request

Comment: I got it to work although I'll give yours a shot. It may come in handy in the future.